# redirect old wordpress ?page_id= to non-wordpress site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I used to have a WP site that I converted to a standard html site. Problem is I found doing a google search that instead of http://www.genealogyinc.com it was returning http://www.genealogyinc.com/?page_id=21, I dont know how many pages are like this but am trying to find a htaccess workaround,  all the ones I found online give me 500 server errors.
Need a rewrite for any ?page_id= cause I dont know how many other numbers are out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, without testing, it would be something like this.
The first line looks for the page_id querystring parameter, and if it meets it, it should pass on to the second line.  The rewrite rule I have below may need some tweaking, but I hope this helps you.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=(.*)$

RewriteRule $ /? [R=301,L]

Comment: Thanks for the response , I tried the code but it had no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the heck I was thinking -- I gave you the wrong querystring parameter...  I edited the rule above, please try it now.